# How to import .NET Chart Control?

Tags: .net

I am working with .NET 4.5 and am trying to use the Chart Control.

I followed the instructions at this URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx

However, when I import the control, I get the following message:

> 'The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are
>   not enabled in the active designer:
>
> Chart
>
> Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer
>   and .NET framework version'

HOw can I get the control to appear in my toolbox?

EDIT:
I am building a Windows Forms app.

Comment: What is your project type.?

Comment: I am building a WIndows Forms app.

Comment: Did you find it by default in the toolbox ? I did the same thing in this tutorial and worked just fine.

Comment: No, I thought I would actually. And when I didn't, I went and tried importing it the way it is outlined in the article. What is it called once it is imported?

Comment: Okie. I found it. It did not appear in the 'All WIndows Forms' area like I thought it would. It appeared under Data. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Though, everything was described on the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on WPF project then you're most likely not going to find Chart Control.So, the solution is to use Chart Control in here http://wpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. I am not using WPF for this project.

Comment: They incorporated it into the framework, but it's still a bit flimsy ... I highly recommend OxyPlot, but seems he already found his solution, and it wasn't for WPF to begin with ... :)